# how to fix module '...' has no attribute '....'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this first module where it need to open file which has the list of entertainment inside it:

```
#testing1
def printEntertainment (venueChoice,entertainmentList,venueList):
    if venueChoice == '1':
        if entertainmentList == '1':
            return('There are no entertainment for VIP Room')

        elif entertainmentList == '2':
            return('There are no entertainment for Executive Room')

        elif entertainmentList == '3':
            return('''
Entertainment for Pool site''')
            x = open('addon/entertainment.txt').readlines()
            desired_lines = [1,2,3]
            output = []
            for desired in desired_lines:
                output.append(x[desired - 1])

            for o in output:
                return("{}.{}".format(output.index(o) + 1, o))

        elif entertainmentList == '4':
            return('''
Entertainment for Banquet Hall''')
            x = open('addon/entertainment.txt').readlines()
            desired_lines = [2,3,4,5]
            output = []
            for desired in desired_lines:
                output.append(x[desired - 1])

            for o in output:
                return("{}.{}".format(output.index(o) + 1, o))
```

and the second module which is to choose the venue and the number for entertainment:

```
#testing2
import testing1    
print('''
1.Vip room     2.Executive room
3.pool site    4. Banquet Hall
''')
venueChoice = input('Please select a venue:')
entertainmentList = input('enter no. for entertainment:')
venueList = None
testing2.printEntertainment (venueChoice,entertainmentList,venueList)

choice = testing2.entertainmentList
venueChoice = input('Please enter choice:')
def calculateEntertainment(choice,venueChoice):

    if choice == '1':
        print(0)

    elif choice == '2':
        print(0)

    elif choice == '3':
        if venueChoice == '1':
            print(2000)
        elif venueChoice == '2':
            print(250)
        elif venueChoice == '3':
            print(400)

    elif choice == '4':
        if venueChoice == '1':
            print(250)
        elif venueChoice == '2':
            print(400)
        elif venueChoice == '3':
            print(1000)
        elif venueChoice == '4':
            print(1500)
```

It seems that I can't use the entertainmentList from `printEntertainment (venueChoice,entertainmentList,venueList)` where I use it at `choice = testing2.entertainmentList` . It will print out `module 'testing1' has no attribute 'entertainmentList'`. 
What should I add to my program to fix it? Thanks

Comment: [Please post the complete, exact error message.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146/why-should-i-post-complete-errors-why-isnt-the-message-itself-enough?cb=1)

Comment: Why did you expect `testing2.entertainmentList` to be a thing? It's not clear what part of this code you were expecting to create `testing2.entertainmentList`.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Hp\Desktop\assignment\FST10014_2_2017_Assignment\Garden\testing1.py", line 11, in <module>
    choice = testing2.entertainmentList
AttributeError: module 'testing1' has no attribute 'entertainmentList' -----the exact error message

Comment: the 'testing2.entertainmentList' is the data from entertainmentList of  the printEntertainment (venueChoice,entertainmentList,venueList) that i want to take @user2357112

Answer (score 0):

I think you're getting multiple things wrong. You're calling a function from a different python file ('testing1.py'). So to call the function it should be `testing1.printEntertainment()` and if you want to save the function's output as `testing2`, you can do it like this: `testing2 = testing1.printEntertainment()`. It also seems like you want to handle variables like class attributes: `testing2.entertainmentList` is trying to get the attribute `entertainmentList` from class `testing2` which you never initialized. So I would suggest you to have a look at some basic tutorials for that again. For you're code, you could just put the two files into one and skip a lot of stuff you're currently doing. But I have no idea what you want to achieve, so here are just some basic improvements which might help you to get the idea:

```
# testing1
def printEntertainment(venueChoice, entertainmentList, venueList):
    if venueChoice == '1':
        if entertainmentList == '1':
            return('There are no entertainment for VIP Room')

        elif entertainmentList == '2':
            return('There are no entertainment for Executive Room')

        elif entertainmentList == '3':
            return('Entertainment for Pool site')
            x = open('addon/entertainment.txt').readlines()
            desired_lines = [1, 2, 3]
            output = []
            for desired in desired_lines:
                output.append(x[desired - 1])

            for o in output:
                return("{}.{}".format(output.index(o) + 1, o))

        elif entertainmentList == '4':
            return('Entertainment for Banquet Hall')
            x = open('addon/entertainment.txt').readlines()
            desired_lines = [2, 3, 4, 5]
            output = []
            for desired in desired_lines:
                output.append(x[desired - 1])

            for o in output:
                return("{}.{}".format(output.index(o) + 1, o))


# testing2
print('''1.Vip room     2.Executive room
3.pool site    4. Banquet Hall''')
# You also should specify what input you want to have (e.g. string or int)
venueChoice = str(input('Please select a venue:'))
entertainmentList = str(input('enter no. for entertainment:'))
venueList = None
testing1 = printEntertainment(venueChoice, entertainmentList, venueList)


def calculateEntertainment(choice, venueChoice):
    if choice == '1':
        print(0)
    elif choice == '2':
        print(0)
    elif choice == '3':
        if venueChoice == '1':
            print(2000)
        elif venueChoice == '2':
            print(250)
        elif venueChoice == '3':
            print(400)
    elif choice == '4':
        if venueChoice == '1':
            print(250)
        elif venueChoice == '2':
            print(400)
        elif venueChoice == '3':
            print(1000)
        elif venueChoice == '4':
            print(1500)


calculateEntertainment(entertainmentList, venueChoice)
```